# Comparative effectiveness of pseudorandom functions, and other factors

Tags: solidity, evm, proof-of-stake

Which of these two is more effective for generating a pseudorandom number?

```
function random() internal view returns (uint) {
    return uint(blockhash(block.number - 1));
}

function random() internal view returns (uint) {
    return uint(keccak256(abi.encodePacked(block.difficulty, block.timestamp)))
}
```

I know both of these could be gamed with some effort, by a miner throwing out a block that doesn't produce a desired result.

However, I also wonder about the likelihood of a rogue actor succeeding: if you have one rogue actor who's trying to mine a block for a "desirable outcome", it's still very possible and likely that someone else will mine that transaction in the meantime, is this correct reasoning?

Also how does PoS affect this calculation, if at all?

Answer (score 0):

> Which of these two is more effective for generating a pseudorandom
> number?

I would say that the second version is "better", but both are bad.

**First version:**

Refers to the previous block hash, so you only need to know block n - 1 to deduce your function's output before its execution. Any user could try to use it, no need to be a miner. If the last block hash is favorable to the user, it only needs to send a high-priority transaction and has good chances of seeing it included in the next block, therefore taking advantage of your pseudo random computation. Simply put, you should never rely on block hash as a source of entropy.

**Second version:**

Uses the current block, so it's a more constrained time window.
Additionally, it requires more computation than the first one but it's still trivial. Only a miner would have access to the block timestamp while it is being created, as until broadcast, the block is local to that miner only. But block timestamp are known to be manipulable, and block difficulty is publicly available knowledge..

So they are both bad, as it is still trivial for any user (1) or miner (1 and 2) to take advantage of it.

---

> However, I also wonder about the likelihood of a rogue actor
> succeeding: if you have one rogue actor who's trying to mine a block
> for a "desirable outcome", it's still very possible and likely that
> someone else will mine that transaction in the meantime, is this
> correct reasoning?

It depends on what is at stake. If there is a lot to gain from attacking your smart contract, chances are that it will happen, and it can be done relatively easily for a strong miner. If not, then you should be fine… But overall you acknowledge a (potentially critical) vulnerability while considering yourself safe based on an assumption… I wouldn't consider that correct reasoning unless you can prove your assumption to be true.

---

> Also how does PoS affect this calculation, if at all?

Ethereum 2.0 PoS uses a [PBFT](https://medium.com/coinmonks/pbft-understanding-the-algorithm-b7a7869650ae) inspired consensus mechanism. It is no longer a race between miners but an election where a leader submits a block proposal to a committee, it wouldn't change much to your vulnerability except that the block proposer wouldn't be competing against anyone, thus attacking your contract might be a bit easier if anything.

I am not aware of any proof system to secure the timestamp or the other variables you use as a source of entropy in Ethereum 2.0.

This [link](https://fravoll.github.io/solidity-patterns/randomness.html) might be of interest to you, in short: if there is no financial incentive to attack your contract, you should be fine (but it's still bad practice). Otherwise, don't rely on public / manipulable sources of entropy and use random Oracles.